# Does this verse of Mahabharata Shanti Parva say that Vayu also alomg with Rudra consumed poison, as some Madhwas claim?

Tags: mahabharata, shiva, vaishnavism, shaivism, madhvacharya

In Shanti Parva, [The 16th verse in
chapter 329 ब्राह्मणमाहात्म्यमग्निषोमीयात्मकम् of BORI edition](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/unic/mbh12_sa.html)

> अमृतोत्पादने पुरश्चरणतामुपगतस्याङ्गिरसो बृहस्पतेरुपस्पृशतो न
> प्रसादं गतवत्यः किलापः अथ बृहस्पतिरपां चुक्रोध यस्मान्ममोपस्पृशतः
> कलुषीभूता न प्रसादमुपगतास्तस्मादद्यप्रभृति
> झषमकरमत्स्यकच्छपजन्तुसङ्कीर्णाः कलुषीभवतेति    तदाप्रभृत्यापो यादोभिः
> सङ्कीर्णाः संवृत्ताः ||१६||

---

The same thing is there in [27th verse of chapter 342 contained Volume 5, Page 2322 of The Gita Press, Gorakhpur Edition.](https://archive.org/download/unabridged-mahabharata-6-volumes-set-in-hindi-by-veda-vyasa-compressed/Mahabharata%20Volume%205.pdf)

[image]

---

The same verse is present in [Kisori Ganguli's English translation in Chapter 343(SECTION CCCXLIII)](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c042.htm)

> On the occasion of churning the Ocean for raising the amrita,
> Vrihaspati of Angiras race sat on the shores of the Ocean for
> performing the rite of Puruscharana. When he took up a little water
> for the purpose of the initial achamana, the water seemed to him to be
> very muddy. At this Vrihaspati became angry and cursed the Ocean,
> saying,--Since thou continuest to be so dirty regardless of the fact
> of my having come to thee for touching thee, since thou hast not
> become clear and transparent, therefore from this day thou shalt be
> tainted with fishes and sharks and tortoises and other aquatic
> animals. From that time, the waters of the ocean have become infested
> with diverse kinds of sea-animals and monsters.

---

The same verse seems to be slightly different in [Southeren Khumbhakonam recension, Verse 27 Chapter 351](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mbhK/mahabharata-k-12-sa.html)

> अमृतोत्पादने पुनर्भक्षणतां वायुसमीकृतस्य विषस्योपगतश्च   तद्भक्षणमिति
> तन्निमित्तमेव चन्द्रकला ब्रह्मणा निहिता। आङ्गिरसबृहस्पतेरुपस्पृशतो न
> प्रसादं गतवत्यः किलापः। अथ  बृहस्पतिरद्भ्यश्चुक्रोध यस्मान्ममोपस्पृशतः
> कलुपीभूता नच प्रसादमुपगतास्ततस्मादद्यप्रभृति
> झषमकरमत्स्यकच्छपजन्तुमण्डूकसंकीर्णाः कलुषीभवतेति।  तदाप्रभृत्यापो
> यादोभिः संकीर्णाः कलुषीभवतेति। तदाप्रभृत्यापो   यादोभिः संकीर्णाः
> संवृत्ताः॥ 12-351-27

---

Now, this verse which is present in Khumbhakonam edition, has a different verse than the others. What is the meaning of ths verse? Is this authentic? Can this verse or the other verse be used to prove that Vayu also along with Rudra or Shiva drank poison during Ocean churning episode?

---

P. S: This is [the post](https://www.instagram.com/p/CiXB6P2rnXo/?igshid=YmMyMTA2M2Y=)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harihi Om.

A basic translation of this shloka is as follows:

> अमृतोत्पादने पुनर्भक्षणतां वायुसमीकृतस्य विषस्योपगतश्च तद्भक्षणमिति तन्निमित्तमेव चन्द्रकला ब्रह्मणा निहिता । आङ्गिरसबृहस्पतेरुपस्पृशतो न प्रसादं गतवत्यः किलापः । अथ बृहस्पतिरद्भ्यश्चुक्रोध यस्मान्ममोपस्पृशतः कलुपीभूता नच प्रसादमुपगतास्ततस्मादद्यप्रभृति झषमकरमत्स्यकच्छपजन्तुमण्डूकसंकीर्णाः कलुषीभवतेति । तदाप्रभृत्यापो यादोभिः संकीर्णाः कलुषीभवतेति । तदाप्रभृत्यापो यादोभिः संकीर्णाः संवृत्ताः ॥ 12-351-27 ॥
>
> Desiring to obtain amrta, on the day of the crescent moon, Shri Vaayu, the consumer of the poison, churned and reduced the intensity of the poison, as per the directions of Brahmaa. Then, Shri Brhaspati touched the water to enable the appearance of amrta, he was not pleased (as it didn’t appear). Angrily, he cursed: “Even after me touching water, it is still contaminated. Thus, the water shall become contaminated with sea animals, thus, the water shall become contaminated with sea animals.”

-Mahaabhaarata (Kumbhakonam edition), Shaanti Parva, Adhyaaya 351, Shloka 27

This shloka is authentic, since this incident of Vaayu consuming the halaahala poison has been mentioned by Shripaada Madhvacharya, in 10th Adhyaaya of the Mahaabhaarata Taatparya Nirnaya. Most scholars consider quotations till the 15th century authentic, since till that time quoting false or unreliable quotations was not an option. There were several scholars present throughout the Indian subcontinent and a Siddhaanta cannot be established obviously with fake quotations, since they would be refuted by other scholars.

Additionally, there is a direct pramaana from the Keshi Sukta of the Rgveda, which mentions this:

> वा॒युर॑स्मा॒ उपा॑मन्थत्पि॒नष्टि॑ स्मा कुनन्न॒मा ।
>
> के॒शी वि॒षस्य॒ पात्रे॑ण॒ यद्रु॒द्रेणापि॑बत्स॒ह ॥
>
> ”Vaayu churned for him, the inflexible ground it when the radiant and along with Rudra, drank the poison, from his cup.”

-Rgveda, Mandala 10, Sukta 136, Mantra 7

One should be aware that these pramaanas are for the Vaishnava interpretation of the churning of the ocean. Other sampradaayas will have different views.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in a philosophical way yes vayu did consumed the poison. Lets see how.:

> *kevalodyamasaṃvītā mamaṃthuḥ kṣīrasāgaram |
> atinirmathanājjātaṃ kṣīrābdheścahalāhalam || trailokyadahane prauḍhaṃ prāptaṃ haṃtuṃ divaukasaḥ |
> **ata ūrdhvaṃ diśaḥ sarvā vyāptaṃ kṛtsnaṃ nabhastalam |**
> grasituṃ sarvabhūtānāṃ kālakūṭaṃ samabhyayāt || **(Sri Skanda Maha Puranam 1:1:9:97-98).***

**[Translation.:].**

> *(Devas and Asuras) With their sheer continuous exertion, they churned the Ocean of Milk. Due to excessive churning, the poison called Halāhala was generated from the Ocean of Milk. It was strong enough to burn down the three worlds. It came up to kill the heaven-dwellers. **It went up still further and spread to all quarters. The entire sky was pervaded by it.** The Kālakūṭa poison advanced to consume all the living beings. **(97-98).***

Vayu means air or atmosphere. So, spreading of the poison into the atmosphere or air can also mean Vayu consuming the Poison in another way. Prd..

I hope this clarifies your queries.